# MongoDb Aggregate group and sum gives weird numbers when adding another field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to get a total count of transaction that happened by Year, Month and State.
If I group and sum by Year and Month - I get correct numbers.

When I add "state" the numbers are off. by a lot.

Here is the query - with the "state" commented out - so I don't have to paste it twice - simply uncommenting the lines will give you what I am trying, that gives wrong numbers.

The results are below -

At first I though I had hundreds of records missing the "address.state" field - but a search for that resulted in only 1 (one) record missing an address object.

```
.find({'address.state':{ $exists: false }})
```

The aggregate query - "state" is commented out...

```
db.getCollection('transactions').aggregate([
    { 
        $match: { type: 'sale' } 
    },
    {
        $project: {
            year: { $year: '$dates.transaction' },
            month: { $month: '$dates.transaction' },
            //state: '$address.state'
        }
    },
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id: { 
                year: '$year', 
                month: '$month', 
                //state: '$state' 
                }, 
                count: { $sum: 1 } 
            } 
        },
    { $sort: { '_id.year': 1 } },
    { $sort: { '_id.month': 1 } },
    //{ $sort: { '_id.state': 1 } },
    { 
        $project: { 
            'year': '$_id.year', 
            'month': '$_id.month', 
            //'state': '$_id.state', 
            'count': '$count', 
            _id:0
        } 
    }
]);
```

Here are the results for the past year

[image: SS of year]

You can see - the First 4 columns are WITH the state data - and I clearly have a bunch of records missing state data - but more importantly - the numbers of the MONTHS aggregate don't even match, neither does the annual total.

I am fairly confident the Group of the 3 columns on the right (sums without the 'state' group) are correct.

Any insight into what I did wrong?

Per request, here is some data.

- This is actual data, and I have been able to recreate the issue using JUST this data and the above query - the missing records were from states TN, TX and VA. I put these records at the bottom of this data dump - the other records got counted and grouped together fine. (actually - had to reduce due to post limit); so I removed a bunch of the "blank state" records, leaving a fair amount of "good" records and all of the "bad" (missing) records - I cannot see why they are not grouped or counted - any help... please.

  /* 1 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e0bf3bba68d2f0017303f70"),
  "address":{ "city":"", "state":"", "zip":"37085" },
  "buyer":"Mykaela",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-01T01:19:55.857Z") }
  }

  /* 94 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e33872a4393d30017ad3739"),
  "address":{ "city":"", "state":"", "zip":"15229" },
  "buyer":"Emily",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-31T01:47:22.058Z") }
  }

  /* 34 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e1df85253aff80017883b8e"),
  "address":{ "city":"Anniston", "state":"AL", "zip":"36207" },
  "buyer":"Marshall",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-14T17:20:18.875Z") }
  }

  /* 32 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e1d2920fe0d0900177f5d38"),
  "address":{ "city":"Alexander", "state":"AR", "zip":"72002" },
  "buyer":"Jonathon",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-14T02:36:16.613Z") }
  }

  /* 13 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e14ec7e93f30c00170f2634"),
  "address":{ "city":"Armuchee", "state":"GA", "zip":"30105" },
  "buyer":"Shiloh",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-07T20:39:26.918Z") }
  }

  /* 80 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e2f97173f8cce00176d64c2"),
  "address":{ "city":"MACON", "state":"GA", "zip":"31220" },
  "buyer":"James",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-28T02:06:15.562Z") }
  }

  /* 62 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e2791773511420017540bc9"),
  "address":{ "city":"Painted Post", "state":"NY", "zip":"14870" },
  "buyer":"Ethan",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-22T00:04:07.701Z") }
  }

  /* 52 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e23a45b3c46750017f65191"),
  "address":{ "city":"Walhalla", "state":"SC", "zip":"29691" },
  "buyer":"Richard ",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-19T00:35:39.967Z") }
  }

  /* 74 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e2e203fbf31900017fa444b"),
  "address":{ "city":"Chapin", "state":"SC", "zip":"29036" },
  "buyer":"Preston",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-26T23:26:55.813Z") }
  }

  /* 21 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e18e4db14400f001737172f"),
  "address":{ "city":"Nairobi ", "state":"TN", "zip":"00100" },
  "buyer":"Gregory ",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-10T20:55:55.239Z") }
  }

  /* 4 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e0cc53c137f2a0017d2f8ca"),
  "address":{ "city":"Waxahachie", "state":"TX", "zip":"75167" },
  "buyer":"Acacia",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-01T16:13:48.014Z") }
  }

  /* 57 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e266a66cd3e010017f50fd5"),
  "address":{ "city":"spring", "state":"TX", "zip":"77379" },
  "buyer":"Melanie",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-21T03:05:10.442Z") }
  }

  /* 63 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e28b3b13511420017540bfb"),
  "address":{ "city":"Abilene", "state":"TX", "zip":"79605" },
  "buyer":"Isreal",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-22T20:42:25.366Z") }
  }

  /* 92 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e32d0d13f8837001779160e"),
  "address":{ "city":"glenn heights", "state":"TX", "zip":"75154" },
  "buyer":"Kohron",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-30T12:49:21.432Z") }
  }

  /* 45 */
  {
  "_id":ObjectId("5e20c621c5fb2700178d2b4e"),
  "address":{ "city":"Barboursville", "state":"VA", "zip":"22923" },
  "buyer":"Harrison",
  "type":"sale",
  "date":{ "transaction":ISODate("2020-01-16T20:22:57.061Z") }
  }

Comment: can you provide some data?

Comment: You have states addresses with empty strings for states, those exist as far as $exists is concerned.

Comment: I would also suggest verifying query results in mongo shell.

Comment: D. SM - correct, there is only ONE record with a malformed 'address' missing a state.
and I am verifying results in Robo 3T. - the total counts match my grouped by month/year totals...So it is the "state" being added that gives the wrong numbers

Comment: The query seems to be accurate when tested in the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BYuyXpaOSNV)

Comment: Joe - first THANK YOU for pointing me to that playground - what a great tool...
but - when I put my full complement of data in for 2020, I've got date for 8 months, and I only get a result that shows Jan (granted for all states...) and Feb for only the blank states... nothing for Mar-Aug...
https://mongoplayground.net/p/TOdQbMCx9ZQ